# How to parse a sitemap index that has compressed links

Tags: java, web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt

I've made a program that reads the /robots.txt and the /sitemap.xml of a page and substracts the available sitemaps and stores them on the `siteMapsUnsorted` list.
Once there I use **crawler-commons** library to analyze if the links are SiteMaps or SiteMapIndexes (cluster of SiteMaps).

When I use it on a normal siteMapIndex it works, the problem occurs in some cases where bigger sites have the list of SiteMapIndexes on a compressed format, e.g:

- **Compressed sitemapIndex:** http://tripadvisor-sitemaps.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/es/sitemap_es_index.xml
- **Normal sitemapIndex:** https://www.infolibre.es/sitemap_index_382e2.xml

---

The code I'm using:

```
SiteMapParser sitemapParser = new SiteMapParser();

for (String sitemapURLStr : siteMapsUnsorted) {
    AbstractSiteMap siteMapCandidate = sitemapParser.parseSiteMap(new URL(sitemapURLStr));
//AbstractSiteMap siteMapCandidate = sitemapParser.parseSiteMap("xml", content , new URL(sitemapURLStr));
    
    // Check if the elements inside the list are SiteMapIndexes or SiteMaps, if they are SiteMapINDEXES, we need to break them down into SiteMaps
    if (siteMapCandidate instanceof SiteMapIndex){
        SiteMapIndex siteMapIndex = (SiteMapIndex) siteMapCandidate;

        for (AbstractSiteMap aSiteMap : siteMapIndex.getSitemaps()){
            if (aSiteMap instanceof  SiteMap){
                String siteMapString = aSiteMap.getUrl().toString();
                System.out.println(siteMapString);
                siteMaps.add(siteMapString);
            } else{
                LOG.warn("ignoring site map index inside site map index: " + aSiteMap.getUrl());
            }
        }
    }
    // If the elements inside the list are individual SiteMaps we add them to the SiteMaps list
    else {
        siteMaps.add(siteMapCandidate.getUrl().toString());
    }
}
```

I've noticed that the method [parseSitemap](https://crawler-commons.github.io/crawler-commons/0.7/crawlercommons/sitemaps/SiteMapParser.html#parseSiteMap-byte:A-java.net.URL-) changes depending the parameters you pass to it, but after trying multiple times I couldnt find a way to handle the compressed elements.

My last alternative would be to program a method that downloads every .tar.gz, decompresses it, reads the decompressed list of links, store them and finally deletes the directory; but that would be **extremelly slow and inefficient**, so first I came here to see if anyone has a better idea/could help me with the parseSitemap().

Thanks to anyone helping in advance.

Comment: As a software engineer at Tripadvisor, I have to ask.  Why are you parsing our sitemaps?

Comment: What package provides the `SiteMapParser` class?  It seems likely that it doesn't support gzip for some reason.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm programing a crawler that has to be able to go to ANY given website, get its sitemap and then read all of its links. I've chosen TripAdvisor as I thought it is a good example of a very big website, and because it has dynamic content. From all the other options I have I use TripAdvisor because I like how well-structured is the sitemap content, and also because this is the example giving me errors because of the compressed SiteMapIndexes

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the package I'm using is crawler-commons, I know Python has much more powerful scrapping tools but I have to do it on Java as this is the language I'm practicing scrapping with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is failing is that Tripadvisor doesn't set the correct mime type on its sitemaps:

```
$ curl --head https://www.tripadvisor.es/sitemap/2/es/sitemap-1662847-es-articles-1644753222.xml.gz
...
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

and the library that are using [only decodes with gzip](https://github.com/crawler-commons/crawler-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/crawlercommons/mimetypes/MimeTypeDetector.java) when the content type is one of:

```java
private static String[] GZIP_MIMETYPES = new String[] { 
  "application/gzip",
  "application/gzip-compressed",
  "application/gzipped",
  "application/x-gzip",
  "application/x-gzip-compressed",
  "application/x-gunzip",
  "gzip/document"
};
```

You could probably work around this by implementing better detection of gzip and xml (like the URL ends in `.xml.gz`) and call the `processGzippedXML` method directly after downloading the sitemap to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I'll have to implement something that gets every link, decompresses it on a folder and reads it, then empty that folder every x time.